# String array out of bounds exception

Tags: android, arrays, string

My string array has around 40 items, so how I can set the length of string[]?
My code:

```
Context context;
String[] mTitle;
String[] mSubTitle;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public MenuListAdapter(Context context, String[] title, String[] subtitle)
        {
    this.context = context;
    this.mTitle = title;
    this.mSubTitle = subtitle;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mTitle.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mTitle[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@SuppressLint("ViewHolder") public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Declare Variables
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtSubTitle;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent,
            false);

    // Locate the TextViews in drawer_list_item.xml
    txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    txtSubTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);

    // Set the results into TextViews
    String[] title = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.title);
    String[] subtitle = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.subtitle);
    txtTitle.setText(title[position]);
    txtSubTitle.setText(subtitle[position]);

    return itemView;
}

}
```

And my string array:

```
<string-array name="title">
<item>10</item>
<item>11</item>
<item>11A</item>
<item>11G</item>
<item>12</item>
<item>12A</item>
<item>12Y</item>
<item>13</item>
<item>13A</item>
<item>13G</item>
<item>13Y</item>
<item>14</item>
<item>14G</item>
<item>15</item>
<item>15A</item>
<item>15Y</item>
<item>16</item>
<item>16A</item>
<item>17</item>
<item>20</item>
<item>22</item>
<item>23</item>
<item>23E</item>
<item>24</item>
<item>25</item>
<item>26</item>
<item>26A</item>
<item>26G</item>
<item>27</item>
<item>29</item>
<item>31</item>
<item>31E</item>
<item>32</item>
<item>33</item>
<item>34</item>
<item>35</item>
<item>36</item>
<item>37</item>
<item>38</item>
<item>42</item>
<item>43</item>
<item>44</item>
<item>M26</item>
</string-array>
```

Where should I declare the length of array? The exact error is:

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4

I do not want to use string list, as I don't know how. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you forgot the closing tag of String-array </string-array> after the last <item>M26</item>

Comment: I don't understand why you need this  `String[] title = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.title);
    String[] subtitle = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.subtitle);`?  when you have `this.mTitle = title;
    this.mSubTitle = subtitle;` and using a model class will be better

Comment: Like @Raghunandan said, you shouldn't be fetching your array again in `getView()`. You should be using mTitle and mSubtitle. Check the length of  both these arrays. The error means that one of these arrays (probably subtitles) only contains 4 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arrays `title` and `subtitle` are not the same length. Check your data out.

You can't set an array length, but you can get it from a property:

```
int number_of_items = title.length;
```

Comment: Well, actually it was a pretty stupid mistake, I just had to make the two arrays the same length. Thanks.